# How to uninstall the GCC compiler on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

How exactly to uninstall GCC on Windows? I did not find the compiler in the Control Panel, not even an `uninstall.exe` file in the `C:\MinGW` folder (or in any other location).

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I already checked this question

Comment: @NateEldredge I downloaded from the [MinGW SourceFourge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download)

Comment: If you already checked that question, what step of the answer causes trouble?

Comment: I did not found the installer in the program manager

Comment: That download-thingy does not seem to be a proper installer. The 2 answers from the linked question tell to just delete folders in that case.

Comment: Oh, ok. I will try deleting the whole folder then